# StartTask V/S RunTask in Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I was writing AWS IAM permissions. Our use case is only `AWS Fargate`. After reading the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html) it seems like `StartTask` is not required for AWS fargate but I will need to give permissions for `RunTask`. Could not find any document related to this?

Can anybody confirm/point to the docs?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[See documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduling_tasks.html)
In your case you have to use RunTask

**Run Task API**

> The **RunTask** action is ideally suited for processes such as batch jobs
>   that perform work and then stop. For example, you could have a process
>   call RunTask when work comes into a queue. The task pulls work from
>   the queue, performs the work, and then exits.

**Start Task API**

> Custom schedulers use the StartTask API operation to place tasks on
>   specific container instances within your cluster.
>
> Custom schedulers are only compatible with tasks using the EC2 launch
>   type. ***If you are using the Fargate launch type for your tasks, the
>   StartTask API does not work***.

Comment: The above information is outdated as of now Start Task supports Fargate also.

Answer (score 0):

Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html

Start Task: For selecting the specific scheduler or selecting specific
container instance type

Run Task : Let ECS place tasks for you.